# Bluetooth won't turn on after turning it off

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 on a Thinkpad T480.

I turned on my Bluetooth, in order to turn in back on to pair a new device, and it won't turn back on. I click the on button in the top right drop down menu in gnome, and on the keyboard via the bluetooth button, but neither affects the state.

The bluetooth Gnome settings don't work either.

I've tried restarting from the terminal, and that doesn't seem to do anything either.

What's might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tryed: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez

Comment: No, haven't. I restarted the machine, and that fixed it.